# Can boot Windows 10 only in safe mode after maintenance

Tags: windows-10, boot

I installed windows 10 32-bit 1803 maintenance on an ASUS EB1033. The machine boots fine in safe mode. When I try to boot in normal mode the windows icon shows, the circle of dots spin for about 30 seconds and then the screen goes blank and nothing else happens. I have downloaded the Windows 10 ISO from microsoft and loaded and booted the ISO from an SD-Card. The boot starts ok but none of the recovery options work. So, for example, if I select "restore from recovery point" the response shown is "Option not supported on this operating system". This "not supported" response occurs for all the repair options offered when I boot the ISO. Are there any options to recover the "full" windows since safe boor works but I can't do anything useful with the machine? The Windows menu cannot be displayed in Safe mode when I press the windows keyboard key or click the start button on the screen. I have run "sfc / scannow" in safe mode but that doesn't get the normal boot to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When in safe mode, use *msconfig* to disable all non-Microsoft services (click **Services**, check **Hide all Microsoft service**, and click **Disable all**), and the **Startup** tab in Task Manager to disable startup applications.

With any luck, this will let you boot in normal mode, at which point you can selectively re-enable services and startup items in order to isolate the problem.